# Extract Table Data into different excel sheet using VBA-Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to extract information based on keywords from a website, which is in tabular format.
Example here for keywords and sample website is

```
apple
LG
Samsung
Nokia

Website = www.wikipedia.com
```

I have kept the keywords in Sheet 1 and the table to be extracted in Sheet 2.
I have an issue with going to next line as the table dimension is not same for all.
I have attached a screenshot too.

[image: Sample-Data]
[image: Function_Error]

This is my code so far, this is sample data only, i have huge keywords to be searched for in my actual work.

```
Sub tableextract()
Dim bot As WebDriver
Set bot = New WebDriver
bot.Start "Chrome"
bot.Get "https://www.wikipedia.org/"

r = 1
While (Len(Range("A" & r)) > 0)

bot.FindElementById("searchInput").SendKeys Range("A" & r)
bot.FindElementByXPath("//i[@class='sprite svg-search-icon']").Click

Dim tbl As Selenium.TableElement
Set tbl = bot.FindElementByXPath("//table[@class='infobox biota']").AsTable

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Clear   'THIS IS OPTIONAL
tbl.ToExcel ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

Dim LastRow As Long
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
'MsgBox "Last Row: " & LastRow
Range(LastRow).Offset(1, 0).Select

r = r + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Not all the items of search has the same xpath `//table[@class='infobox biota`

Comment: @QHarr i Understood your concept here, after i ran your code, it says, " Varaible not defined" and highlights the function.
i have added the screenshot too.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Yes sir , but the main objective is not that.
I can search for 2 sample keywords let's say,
Apple and watermelon , and then there is same XPath.

Comment: @QHarr Hey after removing "Option Explicit" is worked.
But the problem is that function is not working , because i ran the code and it runs for sample (Apple & watermelon) , but the watermelon table overwrites the apple's data.

Comment: @QHarr Yes, it worked perfectly now.
Little changes here and there and it finally worked , thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my tutor's solution (QHarr) I have modified a little so as to directly get the page without clicking on the search button

```
Sub Extract_Tables_Wikipedia()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, bot As WebDriver, tbl As Selenium.TableElement, r As Long, m As Long
    Set bot = New WebDriver
    bot.Start "Chrome"
    Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    r = 1
    With bot
        While (Len(wsSrc.Range("A" & r)) > 0)
            .Get "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" & wsSrc.Range("A" & r)
            Set tbl = .FindElementByXPath("//table[@class='infobox biota']").AsTable
            m = GetLastRow(wsDest)
            tbl.ToExcel wsDest.Range("A" & IIf(m = 1, 1, m + 1))
            r = r + 1
        Wend
    End With
End Sub

Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        GetLastRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for more cleaner code.
Also i'm not able to find Qharr's comments , Strange !

Comment: In fact, QHarr deserves thanks most. I have learned a lot from him.